# Clean Architecture: Layers for decoding messages and working with a map?

Tags: clean-architecture

I work in the field of military aviation. The application is a WPF-App within a fighters aircraft and the machine, which runs the app is connected to the internal data bus of the aircraft and also to the radio.
All communication from and to external sources is done via the aforementioned devices and all of the data comes in the form of a byte array, which has to be decoded.
In order to receive those bytes, multiple libraries are used in the Infrastructure Layer. The bytes are decoded in two steps. First from bytes to more manageable message format containing primitives and then from those primitive messages are transformed into domain objects.
**What is the correct layer for decoding binary messages?**

Also pretty much all of the data has to be displayed on a map. The code for the map is seperated into two projects: One project which handles map logic, like loading of tiles, geometries and so one. The second project is used for WPF presentation and is located in the Presentation layer.
**What is the correct layer for handling map (GIS) logic?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> **What is the correct layer for decoding binary messages?**

This is clearly an Interface Adapter. The only exception to that I can think of is if decoding is your apps only job.

> **What is the correct layer for handling map (GIS) logic?**

This seems like an Interface Adapter. The only exception to that would be business rules that don't know the details of the UI. Push those down.